# Python Wolfram Alpha API: StopIteration

Tags: python, api, wolframalpha, stopiteration

How can I avoid the stopiteration error? I am unaware of any functions or loops that the code may be iterating through.

```
import wolframalpha

client = wolframalpha.Client('My Key is Goes Here')
res = client.query('pi')

print next(res.results).text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used `wolframalpha`, but this looks like it should be

```
for result in res.results:
    print result.text
```

**Edit:** I've now installed `wolframalpha` and I see that that query (and the others I have tried) have no results in `res.results`. Instead, they have `pods`. You can iterate through pods as [in the docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wolframalpha):

```
for pod in res.pods:
    print '{p.title}: {p.text}'.format(p=pod)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of [next](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.next) is what is creating the StopIteration error.
Python's API for Wolframalpha is providing an iterator for you to loop over the results with (`next` just gets the "next" result instead of all of them)

You could trap the error with a try/except clause:

```
try:
    print next(res.results).text
except StopIteration:
    print "No results"
```

Comment: That doesn't really solve the problem though, because nothing will print then.

Comment: If it printed before, it will after.  Getting a StopIteration error when calling next means there is no `next` results.  My solution stops this Exception from propagating (and you could print "no results" in the `except` clause if you like that better).